# Make these 2 sql statements into one with the same functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql statement one;

```
select linkscat.id, linkscat.category 
from linkscat, contentlinks, links 
where contentlinks.linksid = links.id 
  and contentlinks.contentid = @contentid 
  and links.linkscatid = linkscat.id 
order by linkscat.category
```

and sql statement 2 takes a parameter called @linkscat which is 'id' from the statement above;

```
select * from links where linkscatid= @linkscat
```

I'm running into all types of trouble trying to use many sqldatareaders, nested repeaters etc, but it would be great if all the work could be done in the one statement? Is this possible and if so please can you help by posting the final statement?

Thanks greatly, any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using joins, so you can simply add the wanted fields to the select clause:

```
select linkscat.id, linkscat.category, links.* 
from linkscat, contentlinks, links 
where contentlinks.linksid = links.id 
  and contentlinks.contentid = @contentid 
  and links.linkscatid = linkscat.id 
order by linkscat.category
```

Though I would state only the required fields instead of using `*`, and would use explicit joins:

```
select linkscat.id, linkscat.category, links.link, links.name  
from linkscat
  inner join links
   on links.linkscatid = linkscat.id 
  inner join contentlinks
   on contentlinks.linksid = links.id 
where contentlinks.contentid = @contentid 
order by linkscat.category
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select * from links where linkscatid in (
    select linkscat.id
    from linkscat, contentlinks, links 
    where contentlinks.linksid = links.id 
      and contentlinks.contentid = @contentid 
      and links.linkscatid = linkscat.id 
    order by linkscat.category)
```

But I am uncertain of your table formats.  Perhaps it should be `select * from links where id in ...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add the fields you need from the links table to the query directly. I suggest you use actual field names from the links table, rather than *.

```
select linkscat.id, linkscat.category, links.field_1, links.field_2, ...
    from linkscat, contentlinks, links 
    where contentlinks.linksid = links.id 
      and contentlinks.contentid = @contentid 
      and links.linkscatid = linkscat.id 
    order by linkscat.category
```